Convergence in distribution with sequence of values
Suppose $X_n$ is a sequence of discrete random variables which converges in distribution to a discrete random variable $X$. Also assume they all have the natural numbers as support. Now, consider a sequence of natural numbers $x_n$ which converge to some number $x$. Is it true that the following holds?
$ F_{X_n} (x_n) \rightarrow F_{X} (x)$
F is the cumulative distribution function.
If it doesn't hold in general, what conditions would make it true? What can we say if the random variables are continuous and $x_n$ are real numbers? Assume pointwise convergence and that, in the continuous case, the cumulative functions are continuos at ever $x_n$ and at $x$.

$x_n$ converging to $x$ in the natural numbers just means that for all $n>N$ we have $x_n=x$. Since the distribution converges to that of $X$, clearly that should also hold for the cumulative distribution function. But for the continuous case, it depends on the notion of convergence: is it pointwise convergence or does it converge with respect to some norm? Also properties of the density function, like continuity or boundedness may be relevant.

Oh, that's true, thank you. For the continuous case, assume pointwise convergence. Also, maybe assume the cumulative functions are continuous at every $x_n$ and at $x$. I'll add that to the question.

Suppose $F$ is continuous and $(x_n)_n$ are real numbers converging to some real $x$. We have that $F_n$ converge uniformly to $F$ on any given $[a,b],a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. For all $n$ large enough we have that $x_n$ belong in a closed neighborhood $K$ of $x$, so for all $n$ large enough we have $|F_n(x_n)-F(x_n)|\leq \sup_{y \in K}|F_n(y)-F(y)|<\varepsilon/2$. Also, since $F$ is continuous, we have $|F(x_n)-F(x)|<\varepsilon/2$ for all $n$ large enough. We conclude that $|F_n(x_n)-F(x)|<\varepsilon$ for all $n$ large enough, so $F_n(x_n)\to F(x)$.
If $F$ is discontinuous and $(x_n)_n$ are real numbers converging to some real $x$, the statement is not true in general. Counterexample where $F_n$ are all continuous: $F_n(y)=(n+1)y-n$ if $1-\frac{1}{n+1}\leq y<1$, $F_n(y)=1$ if $y\geq 1$ and $0$ otherwise; $F(y)=1$ if $y\geq 1$ and $0$ otherwise; $x_n=1-\frac{1}{n+1}$, $x=1$. We have $F_n(x_n)=0$ but $F(x)=1$.
